# Cannot import .tflite model on android module

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, gradle, tensorflow-lite

I have to import a .tflite model on my android project, in particular inside a library module.

Following the official documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android) I right-clicked on my library module, then **New** > **Other** > **TensorFlow Lite Model**. So, I have selected the .tflite model I wanted to import and checked the option "*Automatic add build feautres and dependencies to build gradle*"

But when I try to sync my library build.gradle file I get the following error

> Could not create task ':MyLibrary:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
>
> Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.

After some attempts I have found out that this related to the following lines in my library build.gradle file:

```
buildFeatures {

    mlModelBinding true

}
```

but I don't know why, also because when I do the exact same procedure in my app module (instead of my library module), everything works fine.

Comment: Me too, Have you a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your my library module.

You may try the existing app like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android), and replace the tflite model in `assets`. Usually, you can adapt a model from a working example.